# A good program to get the game data from Diablo 2

Tags: mods, diablo-ii, cheats

Looking for a tool to get current character data (hp,mana,exp,gold, etc.) from the current version (1.13) of Diablo 2. Its fine if it just works for single player, and even an out of date tool is better than nothing.

Comment: I know it is a bit analog, but doesn't a pen and paper work?

Comment: Eh, I need to access the information programatically for a mod I'm writing. Should I be asking this on stackoverflow?

Comment: @zergylord: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ is the proper place for this IMHO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [Hero Editor](http://d2sector.net/downloads/index.php?dlid=221&limit=90) you can customize anything.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest [D2Stats Reader](http://www.medianxl.com/t1430-1-13c-d2stats-reader). It can display base character stats (without items), as well as sum of resistances, MF, GF, elemental damage, resistance pierce and breakpoints. Saves a lot of time, one doesn't have to calculate them manually from each item.

[Download](https://hostr.co/4zUV6KbhMthI).